# Как избавиться от этого окна Mozilla?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

При разработке на Yii в Mozilla Firefox неожиданно обнаружился неприятный случай: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что у вас в адресной строке браузера написано при этом?

Comment: @Visman на всех страницах сайта выскакивает это окно

Comment: Это не ответ на мой вопрос, но раз вы уже отметили ответ PashaPash как правильным, можете не отвечать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно аутентификация работает по следующему принципу:

- браузер делает обычный анонимный запрос
- сервер отвечает браузеру 401 кодом со списком доступных методов аутентификации в заголовке WWW-Authenticate
- браузер показывает диалог для ввода имени и пароля пользователю
- браузер отправляет повторый запрос, но уже с именем и паролем

В этом механизме аутентификацию всегда запрашивает именно сервер, и пользователь всегда видит диалог логина перед отправкой имени и пароля на сервер.

Но есть и более прямой способ - вписать имя и пароль прямо в адресную сроку, в формате http://user@example.com/ или http://user:password@example.com/. Тогда браузер пропустит все, кроме последнего пункта, и сразу отправит имя и пароль.

Проблема в том, что пользователя можно обмануть, и заставить его перейти по адресу вида http://www.paypal.com@example.com/ - добавив после paypal.com побольше символов, чтобы example.com не был так заметен. Показать там форму логина внешне похожую на нужный сайт - и пользователь ничего не заметит.

Поэтому мозилла ругается на попытки сделать запрос по url c именем/паролем в них.  Если вы не задумывали такого поведения - ищите битый url у себя на странице.